# Multiple columns in RadTreeView

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, telerik, radtreeview

Is there any way to provide multiple columns in RadTreeView with column headers? I know this can be achieved using RadTreeListView, but I dont want to use that as that doesn't support Hierarchical data template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RadTreeListView` allows you to display items in a hierarchical structure using the `HierarchyColumnIndex` property. See the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreelistview-features-hierarchy-column.html) for more details.

You can combine that feature with the ability to create your own [templates](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreelistview-templates-structure.html) in order to achieve the result you want.

Hopefully that helps.